# Unexpected garbage value

Tags: c++, variables, memory

for some reason I am getting unexpected garbage values on a variable that has an assigned initialization.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "fmttime.h"                    // Include for formattime interface
#include <strstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

static int monthindex;                  // Lookup table index
static const int milli = 1000;          // Constant value for ms conversion
static const int epochyear = 1970;      // Epoch year 1970
static const int leapy = 4;             // Number of years for a leapyear
using namespace std;

struct Monthpairs                       // Fields for month & day lookup table
{
    const char* mon;                    // Months
    int day;                            // Days
};

Monthpairs months[] =                   // Lookup table for months & days
{
    {"Jan", 31},
    {"Feb", 28},
    {"Mar", 31},
    {"Apr", 30},
    {"May", 31},
    {"Jun", 30},
    {"Jul", 31},
    {"Aug", 31},
    {"Sep", 30},
    {"Oct", 31},
    {"Nov", 30},
    {"Dec", 31},
};

// Structure which will contain the human readable local
// time values
struct ExpandedTime
{
    int et_usec;        // Number of Milliseconds local time
    int et_sec;         // Number of Seconds local time
    int et_min;         // Number of minutes local time
    int et_hour;        // Number of hours local time
    int et_day;         // Day of the month local time
    int et_mon;         // Month of the year local time
    int et_year;        // Our current year (2013 present)
};

// Function prototype for Expanded time function
ExpandedTime* localTime(struct timeval* tv, ExpandedTime* etime);

// Expanded time will take the Epoch time and convert into days,
// months years, hours, minutes etc and then store this back into
// the Expanded Structure

ExpandedTime* localTime(
                        struct timeval* tv,     // Pointer to timeval struct
                        ExpandedTime* etime     // '' '' to expandedtime strct
                        )
{
    tzset();                                    // Corrects for timezone

    int epochT = (tv->tv_sec) - timezone;       // Epoch seconds with
    int epochUT = tv->tv_usec;                  // epochtime microseconds
    int edays;                                  // Days since epochtime
    int days4years = 1460;                      // Number of days in 4 years
    int fouryears;                              // Number of 4 year periods
    int remaindays;                             // Number of days leftover
    int tempdays;                               // Holds value of remaindays

    int monthtracker = 0;                       // Number of TOTAL months passed
                                                // since current 4 year period
    int daysgoneby = 0;                         // Number of days passed
                                                // since current 4 year period

    etime->et_usec = (epochUT/milli) % milli;   // Find the milliseconds
    etime->et_sec = epochT % 60;
    epochT /= 60;                               // Turn into minutes

    etime->et_min = epochT % 60;
    epochT /= 60;                               // Turn into hours

    if (localtime(&tv->tv_sec)->tm_isdst !=0)
        etime->et_hour = (epochT % 24) + 1;     // Hours with DST correction
    else
        etime->et_hour = (epochT % 24);

    edays = tv->tv_sec / 86400;                 // Turn into days since epoch

    fouryears = edays / days4years;
    remaindays = edays % days4years;            // Determines which 4 year perio
    tempdays = remaindays;

    for (monthindex = 0 ; tempdays >= 0 ; ++monthindex)
    {
        daysgoneby += months[monthindex].day;   // Keeps track of days passed

        tempdays -= months[monthindex].day;

        if (monthindex >= 11)                   // Resets counter for 12 months
        {
            monthindex = 0;
        }
        ++monthtracker;
    }

    etime->et_day = monthindex; // (tempdays + months[monthindex].day);

    // This will take the number of months passed in current 4 year period
    // and add it to the epoch year of 1970 to find the current year

    etime->et_year = (monthtracker / 12)  + (fouryears * 4) + epochyear;

    return etime;
}

// Formats epoch time passed from a main function to a
// human readable string
char* formatTime(
                 struct timeval* tv,     // Pointer to timeval struct
                 char* buf,              // Pointer to char buf
                 size_t len              // size of buffer
                 )
{
    struct ExpandedTime etime2;         // Struct object declaration

    if (len > 0)                        // Will only print to valid sized buffer
    {
        localTime(tv, &etime2);
        ostrstream oss(buf, len);

        // Prints the time and date into a human readable string and
        // places it in the supplied buffer from plot.cc

        oss << etime2.et_year << " " <<  months[monthindex].mon << " " <<
        etime2.et_day << " " << setw(2) << etime2.et_hour << ":"
        << setfill('0') << setw(2) << etime2.et_min << ":" << setfill('0')
        << setw(2) << etime2.et_sec << ":" << setfill('0') << setw(3) <<
         etime2.et_usec << ends;
    }

    else if (len <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Sorry the length of the buffer is too small cannot write" << en
    }

    return buf;
}
```

Basically tempday is evaluating to some large negative value -185338583 for example. Even though its assigned to an initial value of 1212, theres no reason for tempdays to even be in this area of magnitude. Im assuming i must have done something to the programs allocation of memory? This is something that I cannot figure out.

I will say that initially I had this code, then changed the for loop to a while loop. I then changed it back to the exact same for loop and thats when tempdays started to act odd. My assumption is some sort of garbage value is being output by tempdays....i have no clue why.

Comment: There is everything but the initialization of tempday to 1212.

Comment: tempdays is initialized to remaindays which is = 1212. I checked the remaindays variable value. Its once the tempdays enters the for loop it comes out as garbage....

Comment: Your loop is weird; it misses January every time it wraps around; is that intentional?

Comment: No it is not intentional. I am currently trying to resolve that. However the bigger concern is why tempdays is evaluating to some ridiculous random neg number. Its a different number everytime i run the program.

Comment: Well, while I can see a few issues in the code, I can't see anything that would cause that behaviour. All I can suggest is to `cout` the heck out of it to make sure the values are doing as you expect (a `cout` inside the loop would be a good start)

Comment: I just commented out the for loop and printed tempdays and WITHOUT the for loop i do get the proper value of 1212. Is it possible the for loop is corrupting the memory? Also, you say I skip January on every loop? I am not sure I see that...

Comment: each time it rolls around you set `monthindex = 0;`, but at the end of each iteration you tell it to `++monthindex`, so it jumps from 11 to 1. Set it to -1 or refactor your loop to be friendlier. And no, the loop doesn't set any memory which isn't well defined. But it could be *reading* bad memory somehow.

Comment: Ah right. Could that be the issue? Also, would this be a case of memory leak? Maybe if i called tempday something else it may fix the probelm. Thanks for your help by the way, I've been doing this for 4 hours now and my frustration is throught the roof.

Comment: That is probably not the issue, it should yield incorrect result but not what you're describing. One request for you - can you please print out the values (days) of months right before the loop? Any chance you changing them anywhere in your code by mistake?

Comment: I just checked them out after the loop and they are all in accordance. I really don't think Im changing them anywhere in the code at all. Im just so frustrated by this. It makes no logical sense. I was having this issue when I left certain things uninitialized but now Im certain most things are properly initialized...

Comment: Could I be pointing my months[].day table to a null value or something? tempdays HAS to go in as the value 1212 into the loop. I checked that by commenting out the forloop and then printing out tempday....

Comment: It's possible but I doubt it. What I think you should do is start removing lines from your code (not the loop though) like the output prints, and then the calculations before the loop etc'. And after each line you remove run your code until you can spot the problem. And then update the question with more data (like an example input).

Comment: Ok, I'm just guessing here and it's probably not it but try and change all your "int" to "long int".

Comment: I tried, unfortunately no change...Im pretty close to giving up but thanks anyways.

Comment: Okay...its now working properly after i fiddled with it... this is really odd.